Munkres skips showing that a collection forms a subbasis
I have attached a proof for a theorem from Munkres Topology. Theorem says the set $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for the product topology on $X \times Y$. So technically in the proof we should show that $\cup \mathcal{S} = X \times Y$ (definition of subbasis that Munkres has) then move onto showing that the topology generated by $\mathcal S$ is same as product topology on $X \times Y$. But author skips this in proof.
Why? What am I missing here which implies the above condition?


But the author skips this in the proof. Why? Because the author believes that it is better as an exercise for you to fill in the details.

Actually, I proved it myself first then saw his proof and found this part missing. On top of that there was no statement by author which hints towards fill in the details or left as an exercise. I see most of his proofs as source of verification :)

You may discover, in your future mathematical readings, that authors leave many small steps for their readers to fill in, with no hints towards the details nor statements that it is an exercise.

Indeed, according to Munkres himself:

A subbasis $\mathcal{S}$ for a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$. The topology generated by the subbasis $\mathcal{S}$ is defined to be the collection $\mathcal{T}$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$.

Although the condition is trivial to check in this case, it should have been at least mentioned in the proof.
However...
The condition that the union of $\mathcal{S}$ be equal to the whole space is actually dispensable in the definition of a subbasis in the first place. The point of a subbasis is to provide a minimalistic family of sets that we declare open, from which we can compute all open sets. This leads to the functional definition:

A family $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of $X$ is a subbasis of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ provided that $\mathcal{T}$ is the smallest (with respect to inclusion) topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal{S}$.

Note that since the family of all topologies on $X$ containing $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under arbitrary intersections, by the standard reasoning there always exists the smallest such topology. We call it the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$. In particular, the definition makes sense and captures the idea of a subbasis regardless of whether the union of $\mathcal{S}$ is $X$ or not. For instance, the smallest topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal{S} = \varnothing$ is $\{ \varnothing, X \}$, so $\varnothing$ is a subbasis of the antidiscrete topology, where literally no set is open unless it needs to be.
Sometimes easier to work with is the explicit definition:

A family $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of $X$ is a subbasis of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ provided that $\mathcal{T}$ consists precisely of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$.

It is a standard exercise to show that these definitions are equivalent. In particular, an arbitrary family $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of $X$ is a subbasis of a unique topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, regardless of whether the union of $\mathcal{S}$ is $X$ or not.
Then where does the condition come from?
The confusion in demanding that the union be equal to $X$ may originate from a narrow understanding of the term "finite intersections". In this context (as well as many others) it is customary to allow the empty intersection as a special case of a finite intersection, one which yields $X$ as the result. This follows from the localized definition of intersection: when $\mathcal{A}$ is a family of subsets of a fixed universe $U$, we let
$$\bigcap \mathcal{A} := \{ a \in U : (\forall A \in \mathcal{A}) \, a \in A \}.$$
This is not as unnatural as one may think, partly because there is another standard set-theoretic operation that needs an ambient universe to be well-defined: the complement
$$A^c = \{ a \in U : a \notin A \}.$$
However, blindly applying the unlocalized set-theoretic definition of intersection:
$$\bigcap \mathcal{A} := \{ x : (\forall A \in \mathcal{A}) \, x \in A \}$$
to the empty family, $\mathcal{A} = \varnothing$, leads to the unpleasant result that $\bigcap \mathcal{A}$ is the set of everything (set of all sets), which does not exist. For this reason some people are uncomfortable allowing empty intersections, and for them finite intersections means intersections of non-empty finite families.
With this narrower understanding of the term, a family $\mathcal{S}$ no longer gives a topology unless the union of $\mathcal{S}$ equals $X$. Specifically, the condition $X \in \mathcal{T}$ fails, where $\mathcal{T}$ denotes the family of all unions of finite intersections of $\mathcal{S}$, as in the "explicit" definition. In this case (when the union of $\mathcal{S}$ is not $X$) the two definitions provided here are no longer equivalent as well.
Personally, I regard it natural to always consider the localized intersection and thus allow the intersection of the empty family yielding the universe. On the other hand, the condition that the union of a subbasis be equal to $X$ feels unnatural and unrelated to the idea behind the notion of subbasis itself. That's why I think Munkres needlessly put the condition there, and perhaps that was the reason why he later forgot about it himself too.

thanks for the "explicit" definition. I haven't seen that one before this.

I'm glad this was helpful, but isn't the "explicit" definition exactly the same as in Munkres' book? @not_a_math_guy

In Munkres's book, he gives definition of subbasis as $\cup \mathcal{S} = X$. He gives a similar definition for "topology generated by subbasis". As you have mentioned, the condition $\cup \mathcal{S} = X$ is automatically satisfied if we allow empty intersection in finite intersections.

If you insist that every item in a definition gets a mention, then yes, he's missed that one. And for some sub-bases it could be a difficult item to check, thus important to mention. (Though I confess I don't believe I've ever run into one. Perhaps if one is working in a complicated function space this point could require an existence proof?)
However, in this case $X$ is an open subset of $X$, so $X\times Y =\pi_1^{-1}(X) \in \mathcal S$. Since the whole space $X\times Y$ is in your collection $\mathcal S$, it's trivial that the union of your collection is the whole space.
